# Switching Between windowed and full screen in OpenGL/GLFW 3.2

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am in the process of learning OpenGL on Linux but I can't get mode switching working (windowed to full screen and back).

The window appears to be going into full screen but but not looking correct.  To switch modes a new window is being created and old one destroyed.

```
void OpenGLWindow::FullScreen(bool fullScreen, int width, int height)
{
    GLFWwindow *oldHandle = m_window;

    m_fullscreen = fullScreen;
    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;

    m_window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, m_caption.c_str(),
        fullScreen ? m_monitor : NULL, m_window);

    if (m_window == NULL)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to recreate window.");
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(oldHandle);

    m_camera->Invalidate();

    // Use entire window for rendering.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    if (m_keyboardHandler) SetKeyboardHandler(m_keyboardHandler);
}
```

**Initial Window**
[image]

**Full Screen (incorrect)**
[image]

**Return to Windowed**
[image]

**Updates to Question**

I have updated the code to use your code and getting the same issue.  On your suggestion I am now updating the camera, but again no avail :(

```
void OpenGLCamera::Invalidate()
{
    RecalculateProjection(m_perspProjInfo->Width(), m_perspProjInfo->Height());
    m_recalculateViewMatrix = true;
    m_recalculatePerspectiveMatrix = true;
    m_recalculateProjectionMatrix = true;
}

void OpenGLCamera::RecalculateProjection(int width, int height)
{
    float aspectRatio = float(width) / height;
    float frustumYScale = cotangent(degreesToRadians(
        m_perspProjInfo->FieldOfView() / 2));

    float frustumXScale = frustumYScale;

    if (width > height) 
    {
        // Shrink the x scale in eye-coordinate space, so that when geometry is
        // projected to ndc-space, it is widened out to become square.
        m_projectionMatrix[0][0] = frustumXScale / aspectRatio;
        m_projectionMatrix[1][1] = frustumYScale;
    }
    else {
        // Shrink the y scale in eye-coordinate space, so that when geometry is
        // projected to ndc-space, it is widened out to become square.
        m_projectionMatrix[0][0] = frustumXScale;
        m_projectionMatrix[1][1] = frustumYScale * aspectRatio;
    }
}
```

Rabbid : When I resize:

[image]

Rabbid : When I go to full screen:
[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the following, I'll describe a small but handy class, which deals with resizing a GLFW window and handles switch fullscreen window on and off.
All the used GLFW functions are well documented in the [GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html).

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>

class OpenGLWindow
{
private:

    std::array< int, 2 > _wndPos         {0, 0};
    std::array< int, 2 > _wndSize        {0, 0};
    std::array< int, 2 > _vpSize         {0, 0};
    bool                 _updateViewport = true;
    GLFWwindow *         _wnd            = nullptr;
    GLFWmonitor *        _monitor        = nullptr;

    void Resize( int cx, int cy );

public:

    void Init( int width, int height );
    static void CallbackResize(GLFWwindow* window, int cx, int cy);
    void MainLoop ( void );
    bool IsFullscreen( void );
    void SetFullScreen( bool fullscreen );
};
```

When creating the window, then the user function pointer (`glfwSetWindowUserPointer`) is set to the window management class. And the resize callback is set by `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback`. After the window is created its current size and position can be get by `glfwGetWindowPos` and `glfwGetWindowSize`.

```
void OpenGLWindow::Init( int width, int height )
{
    _wnd = glfwCreateWindow( width, height, "OGL window", nullptr, nullptr );
    if ( _wnd == nullptr )
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        throw std::runtime_error( "error initializing window" ); 
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( _wnd );

    glfwSetWindowUserPointer( _wnd, this );
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback( _wnd, OpenGLWindow::CallbackResize );

    _monitor =  glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
    glfwGetWindowSize( _wnd, &_wndSize[0], &_wndSize[1] );
    glfwGetWindowPos( _wnd, &_wndPos[0], &_wndPos[1] );
    _updateViewport = true;
}
```

When the resize notification occurs, then the pointer to the window management class can be get by `glfwGetWindowUserPointer`:

```
static void OpenGLWindow::CallbackResize(GLFWwindow* window, int cx, int cy)
{
    void *ptr = glfwGetWindowUserPointer( window );
    if ( OpenGLWindow *wndPtr = static_cast<OpenGLWindow*>( ptr ) )
        wndPtr->Resize( cx, cy );
}
```

Any change of the window size is notified and the new window size is stored (`glfwGetWindowSize`):

```
void OpenGLWindow::Resize( int cx, int cy )
{
    _updateViewport = true;
}
```

When the window size has changed, then the viewport has to be suited to the window size ([`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml)). This can be done in the main loop of the application:

```
void OpenGLWindow::MainLoop ( void )
{
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(_wnd))
    {
        if ( _updateViewport )
        {
            glfwGetFramebufferSize( _wnd, &_vpSize[0], &_vpSize[1] );
            glViewport( 0, 0, _vpSize[0], _vpSize[1] );
            _updateViewport = false;
        }

        // ..... render the scene

        glfwSwapBuffers(_wnd);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

If the current window is in full screen mode, can be achieved by asking for the monitor that the window uses for full screen mode (`glfwGetWindowMonitor`):

```
bool OpenGLWindow::IsFullscreen( void )
{
    return glfwGetWindowMonitor( _wnd ) != nullptr;
}
```

To switch the full screen mode on and off, `glfwSetWindowMonitor` has to be called, either with the monitor for the full screen mode, or with `nullptr`:

```
void OpenGLWindow::SetFullScreen( bool fullscreen )
{
    if ( IsFullscreen() == fullscreen )
        return;

    if ( fullscreen )
    {
        // backup window position and window size
        glfwGetWindowPos( _wnd, &_wndPos[0], &_wndPos[1] );
        glfwGetWindowSize( _wnd, &_wndSize[0], &_wndSize[1] );
        
        // get resolution of monitor
        const GLFWvidmode * mode = glfwGetVideoMode(_monitor);

        // switch to full screen
        glfwSetWindowMonitor( _wnd, _monitor, 0, 0, mode->width, mode->height, 0 );
    }
    else
    {
        // restore last window size and position
        glfwSetWindowMonitor( _wnd, nullptr,  _wndPos[0], _wndPos[1], _wndSize[0], _wndSize[1], 0 );
    }

    _updateViewport = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to not create a new Window with `glfwCreateWindow` when you just want to switch between windowed and fullscreen. Use `glfwSetWindowMonitor` instead.

When you create a window with fullscreen enabled, you have to pass arguments which are compatible with a video mode on the monitor. You can get the standard video mode on the primary monitor like this:

```
GLFWmonitor *monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
const GLFWvidmode *mode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor);
```

and to switch to fullscreen:

```
glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, monitor, 0, 0, mode->width, mode->height, mode->refreshRate);
```

Just pass a `nullptr`-mode and your own values of course:

```
glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, nullptr, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, windowRefreshRate);
```

And don't forget to resize the viewport and update the camera.

---

Are you resizing the viewport and updating the camera when the user resizes the window?

Comment: I just noticed Rabbid76 has already recommended the same approach as i did in this answer.

Comment: But, his approach has a flaw I can't figure out - the screen goes into full screen and then it goes blue :(  I am seeing 3 calls to Resize() ... Could one of them be corrupting it?

Comment: Are you switching to fullscreen when a button-press occurs? Try to find out if the event of pressing the button repeats and causes a loop. Check if GL is throwing any errors with [glGetError](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error)

Comment: I am using a key press, but there is protection against multiple presses.  Plus I am only seeing the 'switch to xxxx' once.  I was going to try putting a bodge in to stop multiple Resize() calls... They are coming from calls to glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_window, OpenGLWindow::CallbackResize);

Comment: Thats strange. How about not calling `Resize` if the width and height didn't change inside the callback function.

Comment: Are you calling glfwSetWindowSizeCallback again after switching to fullscreen? You don't have to call it again because you aren't destroying and creating a new window.

Comment: The callback is triggered internally by GLFW unfortunately

Comment: Updating the viewport can't possibly trigger it.. ?

Comment: Thank you @ Rabbid76 and @ShroomPow - your solutions **DID** work, but due to a defect 1085 (github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1085) it wasn't behaving as expected.  I am using a fix which is in the dev branch of GLFW - I assume it will go into the 3.3 release.  PHEW!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. Assuming that `glfwCreateWindow` will set the resolution to `width` * `height` in fullscreen mode is not correct. The [GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344) states (emphasis mine):

   > For full screen windows, the specified size becomes the resolution of the window's desired video mode. As long as a full screen window is not iconified, the supported video mode **most closely matching the desired video mode** is set for the specified monitor.
2. Assuming that the window size is specified in "pixels" is not correct either.Quoting the [relevant part of the documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_fbsize) again:

   > While the size of a window is measured in screen coordinates, OpenGL works with pixels. The size you pass into `glViewport`, for example, should be in pixels. On some machines screen coordinates and pixels are the same, but on others they will not be. There is a second set of functions to retrieve the size, in pixels, of the framebuffer of a window.

Issues 1 and 2 can be solved by simply calling `glfwGetFramebufferSize` after the window was created. This leaves us with issue 3:

3. You call `glViewport` without having a current GL context -
   resulting in undefined behavior, and especially in not setting the viewport at all. Now that is actually an interesting one, because the initial viewport for the new context will be the full new window, so that your mistakes 1 and 2 have no direct effect. They still might have some effect later if your code relies on `m_width` and `m_height` containing useful values, though.

Comment: Does that mean I all I would need to do is to move the viewport call after I making the context current?

Comment: Most likely not. As I stated, by not doing `glViewport` in your context, you should already get the right one. I did list a couple of issues in your code. But your question does not contain an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I cannot tell you what exactly the root cause of your issue is.

Comment: I thought of how to generate a MCVE but to show the issue  would involve model loading, camera and rendering

Comment: If an MCVE would involve model loading, then model loading is by definition part of the issue. However, I don't see why that has to be the case. It would be enough to render a simple quad to see where it would end up.

Comment: I am running on a retina mac, I was wondering if that could have an effect on how I mode change?